# How to find the square roots of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, radicals

Square root of a matrix **A** is not a unique matrix, generally.

How to find all the square roots of a matrix, in particular the following matrix **B**:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

other than forming 9 equations in 9 variables as:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

In particular, is there any square root of **B** that has all elements as real numbers.

Comment: Well, if you have one square root, the opposite is also a square root; so square roots of matrices are almost never unique, strictly speaking.

Comment: For diagonal matrices, just take square roots of diagonal elements and construct a square root as another diagonal matrix. Of course because you can take either square root for each diagonal element, immediately you have $8$ square roots...

Comment: @ArnaudD. What is the opposite of a Matrix?

Comment: For example, any reflection at any plane or any rotation by 180° around any axis is a square root of the identity

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen reflection at any _Plane_ and _rotation_ by 180, what do you mean? Are you talking about the geographical interpretation of matrices as rotations in three dimensions?

Comment: In real numbers, the square root is almost never unique $\sqrt 4 = \pm 2$, but we usually put a convention to consider only the positive one.
In matrix analysis it is the same: every positive semidefinite matrix has a uniqe positive semidefinite square root, but in general is far to be the only square root possible

Comment: @Truth-seek The opposite of $A$ is $-A$, the matrix with all elements multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: @Arnaud D. Ok got it. I call it the negative of the matrix. So, thought opposite was something else

Comment: @Exodd What about $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: yup, totally forgot that the matrices of base change can be complex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no guarantee that a real matrix has a square root with real coefficients.  In this case however you may find for e.g. 
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mp1 \\ 0 & \pm1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now $M^2=(-M)^2=B$. This is easier to see if you consider the $B$ matrix as decomposed diagonally into identity matrix $I_1$ and $-I_2$. Now $-I_2$ can be considered a rotation by $\pi$, hence it has a real square root which is the rotation matrix by $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Square roots of matrices, where they exist, are far from unique.  Given the 2×2 identity matrix, one square root is the identity matrix itself.  Another is the negative of the identity matrix.  Or just make either one element -1.  Or the "interchange marrix" where the diagonal elements are zero and the nondiagonal elements 1.

And so on.

Comment: Thn u so much for the help.